# DVR software for Linux

Tags: video, free-software

I think the DVR/CCTV follow some convention, but most of them use activeX for online access. I'm curious if some documentation/specification exist so I could make my own client (Linux), standalone (C, C++, Py, Java) or in-browser (Java). The ports are known - the DVR settings show them - but the format, PTZ channel, and so on are in deep dark.

Could someone point to a (open/free) documentation, or an opensource app to use it as a start?